# curl. Couldn't resolve host

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to get content from the site http://www.akimat-sarkan.gov.kz/ by curl. But it returns error Couldn't resolve host 'www.akimat-sarkan.gov.kz'.
My function:

```
function get_web_page($url)
{
  $uagent = "Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.14";  
  $ch = curl_init( $url );   
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);   
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $uagent);  
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 120); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);        
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);   
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,"d://coo.txt");    
  $content = curl_exec( $ch );
  $err     = curl_errno( $ch );
  $errmsg  = curl_error( $ch );
  $header  = curl_getinfo( $ch );
  curl_close( $ch );     
  $header['errno']   = $err;
  $header['errmsg']  = $errmsg;
  $header['content'] = $content;
  return $header;
}
$site = get_web_page('http://www.akimat-sarkan.gov.kz');
$site = $site['content'];
echo $site;
```

Comment: It must be something else, because your code works fine.

Comment: Works  fine on my system..

Comment: It's working fine..

Comment: all of you got any content of this site?

Comment: Maybe you've executed it too many times and they've blocked your IP..

Comment: thanks for your answers! it seems that my IP was blocked, because I try do it from other server and it works